# Telerik ScriptRegistrar moving around script load order, causing error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

Here is the ScriptRegistrar code:

```
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false).jQueryValidation(true)
    .DefaultGroup(group => group
        .Combined(false)
        .Compress(false)
    )
    .Scripts(s => s.AddGroup("myGroup", group => group
            .Add("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")
            .Add("~/Scripts/2012.3.1017/telerik.common.min.js")
            .Add("~/Scripts/2012.3.1017/telerik.upload.min.js")
            .Add("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js")
            .Add("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")
            .Add("~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.min.js")
            .Add("~/Scripts/hiring.js")
        )
    )
)
```

How it looks on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/2012.3.1017/telerik.common.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/2012.3.1017/telerik.upload.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/hiring.js"></script>
```

It switched my order, loading jQuery-dependent scripts before jQuery.